# How can i show my own Google map with placemark labels?

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-earth

I created a map with Google Maps, for my guests.
I need to show road names and directions. Google maps shows it well.

But i also need to show the labels of placemarks.
So they can know the name of the places.
Google Earth can show it.
But (even i only select Roads as layer), it is not readable for a street walker.

How can i combine street names (map view) + placemark labels?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps itself, cant do it.

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/ might help - that can plot a Google based Map, and plot labels.